# Can I use PDO::FETCH_GROUP to group results by two values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, pdo

I'm using PHP and PDO to retrieve a set of values from a database and then group by the first column, with this code:

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

This means that if my data is in this format:

```
|Column1    |Column2    |Column3|
|1          |2          |a|
|1          |2          |b|
```

It returns it as:

```
1: {
     [Column2: 2, Column3: a],
     [Column2:2, Column3:b]
    }
```

How would I group by Column1 and Column2 so I get something like:

```
1: 
   {
    2:
      {
        Column3: a,
        Column3:b
      }
    }
```

Is that possible to do with a combination of PDO constants?

Thanks

Comment: Personally, I never bother with this obscure magic, and fill whatever complex arrays manually, using banal while loop

Comment: The thing with PDO constants is if they happen to do exactly what you want, they're perfect. PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_NUM, for example, would take a huge amount of iterating over arrays and a dozen or so lines of code. The thing I'm finidng is that if they don't do exactly what you want, as you say, you're poking at a magic box that doesn't seem to work

Comment: `FETCH_GROUP` always uses the first column as the key. I don't see any place to specify additional levels of nesting.

Comment: I think it would be better to tell us what you really want to do. Because there may be an easier way instead of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see, it is possible to rebuild array easily by grouping it with one specified column with `PDO::FETCH_GROUP`. What you need is to convert 2-dimension array (result from database) to 3-dimensional array, but **it is not possible** to rebuild it this way.

You need to do it manually via nested loops. It's pretty simple, like these:

```
// let's assume $result is:
$result = [
    [1, 2, 'a'],
    [1, 2, 'b']
];

$newResult = [];
foreach( $result as $row ) {
    $newResult[$row[0]][$row[1]][] = $row[2];
}

var_dump($newResult);
```

It returns:

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "a"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "b"
    }
  }
}
```

and it look like what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

You better `ORDER BY Column1` in your query and group result set in your code like this:

```
$grouped = [];
$lastIdx = null;
foreach ($query->fetchAll() as $result) {
    if ($lastIdx !== $result["Column1"]) {
        $grouped[$result["Column1"]] = [$result];
    } else {
        $grouped[$result["Column1"]][] = $result;
    }
    $lastIdx = $result["Column1"];
}
```