# Is there a way to group a key pair result using PDO's fetch style?

Tags: php, pdo

PDO's `FETCH_KEY_PAIR` can only return a result if there is only 2 columns being queried.

A query like `SELECT category, name, value ..` returns data rows with 3 values and I want to use the PDO's fetch style to get a result set like:

```
array(
    'category_1' => array(
         'name 1' => "value 1",
         'name 2' => "value 2"
    ),
    'category_2' => array(
         'name 3' => "value 3",
         'name 4' => "value 4"
    )    
)
```

The `name` and `value` are a key pair but, I need them to be grouped using the first column, something like `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR|PDO::FETCH_GROUP`. I know this will not work and am hoping if some combination of the supported constants can give me the expected result so I don't have to iterate over the result to get what I want.

Or, in other words, PDO's fetch style solution of the following:

```
$stmt = $database->prepare('Select category, name, value FROM table_name');
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$final = array();
foreach($results as $result) {
    $final[$result['category']][$result['name']] = $result['value'];
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23265998/can-i-use-pdofetch-group-to-group-results-by-two-values