# PDO fetch second column as key of second array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an SQL query :

```
SELECT
    DATE,
    ID_DOMAIN,
    SUM(CLICKS) AS CLICKS,
    SUM(ADS) AS ADS,
    SUM(CONVERSION) AS CONVERSION,
    FROM website_stats
    WHERE ID_USER_PRODUCT_DIFFUSER = :id_user_product_diffuser
    AND DATE >= :date_begin
    AND DATE <= :date_end
    AND ID_DOMAIN != 0
    GROUP BY DATE, ID_DOMAIN;
```

In my `PDO fetchAll`, I use `$sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC | PDO::FETCH_GROUP)`. Then I have this output :

```
array(2) {
  ["2018-09-14"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["ID_DOMAIN"]=>
      string(1) "7"
      ["CLICKS"]=>
      string(4) "1092"
      ["ADS"]=>
      string(4) "1070"
      ["CONVERSION"]=>
      string(3) "269"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(4) {
      ["ID_DOMAIN"]=>
      string(1) "9"
      ["CLICKS"]=>
      string(3) "459"
      ["ADS"]=>
      string(3) "452"
      ["CONVERSION"]=>
      string(2) "56"
    }
  }
  ["2018-09-15"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["ID_DOMAIN"]=>
      string(1) "7"
      ["CLICKS"]=>
      string(3) "914"
      ["ADS"]=>
      string(3) "880"
      ["CONVERSION"]=>
      string(3) "166"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(4) {
      ["ID_DOMAIN"]=>
      string(1) "9"
      ["CLICKS"]=>
      string(3) "365"
      ["ADS"]=>
      string(3) "361"
      ["CONVERSION"]=>
      string(2) "57"
    }
  }
}
```

But for my code, I need the ID_DOMAIN a key in my sub array. It's possible without looping ? I means, just with `PDO::FETCH*` ? In fact, I need an array just like this :

```
array(2) {
  ["2018-09-14"]=>
  array(3) {
    [7]=>
    array(3) {
      ["CLICKS"]=>
      string(4) "1092"
      ["ADS"]=>
      string(4) "1070"
      ["CONVERSION"]=>
      string(3) "269"
    }
    [9]=>
    array(3) {
      ["ID_DOMAIN"]=>
      string(1) "9"
      ["CLICKS"]=>
      string(3) "459"
      ["ADS"]=>
      string(3) "452"
      ["CONVERSION"]=>
      string(2) "56"
    }
  }
  ["2018-09-15"]=>
  array(2) {
    [7]=>
    array(3) {
      ["ID_DOMAIN"]=>
      string(1) "7"
      ["CLICKS"]=>
      string(3) "914"
      ["ADS"]=>
      string(3) "880"
      ["CONVERSION"]=>
      string(3) "166"
    }
    [9]=>
    array(3) {
      ["CLICKS"]=>
      string(3) "365"
      ["ADS"]=>
      string(3) "361"
      ["CONVERSION"]=>
      string(2) "57"
    }
  }
}
```

I search for the good PDO fetch mode for long time but it seems like nobody has this problem in this website :/

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: what are you actually asking? Can ID_DOMAIN be it's own single-level array?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs, I need to build an Histogram, so I need an array with the day in index. And for each day, I need an array where the key is the ID_DOMAIN and containing the statistics of this domain. For example ['DATE_1' => ['ID_DOMAIN_1' => [STATS], 'ID_DOMAIN_2' => [STATS]], 'DATE_2' => ['ID_DOMAIN_1' => [STATS], 'ID_DOMAIN_2' => [STATS]]].

Comment: you should try FETCH_COLUMN on that field and build array ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use PDO::FETCH\_GROUP to group results by two values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23265998/can-i-use-pdofetch-group-to-group-results-by-two-values)

Comment: No, but it's trivial to rearrange the array.