# PHP PDO Fetch as multidimensional array with first column as key, and second & third as key-value pair

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, pdo

I have an MySQL database table that is created like this

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    column1 varchar(50),
    column2 varchar(50),
    column3 int(3)
);

INSERT INTO table1
VALUES ("column1 value1", "column2 value1", 120),
("column1 value1", "column2 value1", 240),
("column1 value2", "column2 value1", 240),
("column1 value2", "column2 value2", 10);
```

On this table. I execute this SQL query:

```
SELECT column1, column2, SUM(column3) FROM table1 GROUP BY column1, column2
```

Is it possible to fetch the result into a multidimensional associative array with `column1` as the "level 1" key, and `column2` & `column3` as a key-value pair?

Desired result:

```
Array
(
    [column1 value] => Array
        (
            [column2 value] => column3 value
        )
)
```

I tried using `PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` as the fetch style argument, but that resulted in:

```
Array
(
    [column1 value] => Array
        (
            [column2 key] => column2 value
            [column3 key] => column3 value
        )
)
```

This is how I am executing my query and fetching the result:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT column1, column2, SUM(column3) FROM table GROUP BY column1, column2");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Is there a fetch style combination that will get me the desired result, or will I have to do this programmatically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use PDO::FETCH\_GROUP to group results by two values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23265998/can-i-use-pdofetch-group-to-group-results-by-two-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you're stuck doing it programmatically, but you could do it with a function in the `fetchAll` call; using `FETCH_GROUP` to do the grouping by the first column and using the function to return the appropriate array from the second and third columns.

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_FUNC,
                          function ($col2, $col3) { 
                              return array($col2 => $col3); 
                          });
```

Note this returns an array with an extra level:

```
Array
(
    [column1 value1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [column2 value1] => 360
                )
        )
    [column1 value2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [column2 value1] => 240
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [column2 value2] => 10
                )
        )
)
```

You can remove the extra level through a combination of `array_map` and `array_reduce`:

```
$result = array_map(function ($arr) {
    return array_reduce($arr, function ($c, $a) {
        $c[key($a)] = reset($a);
        return $c;
    }, []);
}, $result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [column1 value1] => Array
        (
            [column2 value1] => 360
        )
    [column1 value2] => Array
        (
            [column2 value1] => 240
            [column2 value2] => 10
        )
)
```

However it is probably simpler just to loop through the array:

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$out = array();
foreach ($result as $array) {
    $out[$array[0]][$array[1]] = $array[2];
}
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense apparently I should have read your blog - I was not aware of that functionality of `FETCH_UNIQUE` having only seen it in combo with `FETCH_GROUP` in the past. Thanks for the edit. TIL.

Comment: The combination actually makes no sense as it will result in the FETCH_UNIQUE value. But now I am not sure if FETCH_UNIQUE is actually what the OP meant

Comment: If you use `FETCH_GROUP` without `FETCH_UNIQUE`, you get an extra layer in the output (`array($col1 => array(array($col2 => $col3)))`), so `FETCH_UNIQUE` is definitely required.

Comment: Like I said, using FETCH_GROUP with FETCH_UNIQUE just makes no sense, being effectively just FETCH_UNIQUE. and yes, without it you getn an extra level BUT with it you lose a row with data.

Comment: How do you lose a row of data?

Comment: Because of, well, FETCH_*UNIQUE*. His query returns 3 rows but only 2 of them have the unique first column values

Comment: Gotcha. I had used some sample data on my server which didn't show up the problem, using OPs data does. So actually this doesn't work at all... I'll edit with a workaround but also suggest OP unaccepts.

Comment: There is no reason in unaccepting a correct answer tho :)

Comment: @PeterSH it turns out that code did not work correctly, it was causing some data to be lost in the output. You might want to unaccept this answer to see if you can get a better one.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I always like to give them the option - maybe there is a better way (for example yours is better because it just iterates the fetch rather than a fetchAll with a foreach).

Comment: I did realise (after a while) that I was missing a row of data. I ended up using a simple loop like the one suggested at the end, this works just as well.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the hardest part in PDO fetch modes is to tell the *grouping* from *indexing*. Every question related to these modes for some reason have them confused.

From the nature of your query I would say you need the grouping. But in your hairy fetch mode combination you are using FETCH_UNIQUE, which results in the indexing, not grouping.

It's a good thing you provided some MCVE - only few succeeded with it under the PDO tag, but it's a very bad thing that you didn't provide the real desired result, but only a sketch. So I can only guess it must be something like this

```
{
    "column1 value1": {
        "column2 value1": "360"
    },
    "column1 value2": {
        "column2 value1": "240",
        "column2 value2": "10"
    }
}
```

but your current approach is giving you this array *one row short*.

I don't know any fetch modes combination that can give you the desired result but the old good manual fetching always can

```
$sql = "SELECT column1, column2, SUM(column3) sum FROM table1 GROUP BY column1, column2";
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
$data = [];
foreach($stmt as $row) {
    $data[$row['column1']][$row['column2']] = $row['sum'];
}
```

In the end, it turned out that your MCVE is not that good. And it will be a lesson for you, to always create a solid, working and non-contradictory example with the certain desired result that can be compared to the actual outcome.

Comment: This is where I ended up too...

Answer (score 0):

Sadly `PDO::FETCH_GROUP` will only group results by the first fetched column so you won't be able to group by 2 columns.

But you can translate your result to the result you want using `array_map`, `array_combine` and `array_column`

```php
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT column1, column2, SUM(column3) as column3 FROM table1 GROUP BY column1, column2");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$result = array_map(static function ($res) {
    return array_combine(
        array_column($res, 'column2'),
        array_column($res, 'column3')
    );
}, $result);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: I get an empty array `array(1) { ["column1"] => array(0) { } }` using this.